# python | data types and transformations

Tags: python

In the code sequence below, I have no problem for "int to float", but I have a problem for "float to int".

Am I missing something? Can you help me to understand?

```
age         = 28
weight      = 55.6

# int to float

result = float(age)
print(result)

#float to int
result = int(weight)
print(weight)
```

I was expecting an integer result, but the decimal value keeps returning.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fhkB.png)

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: You're capturing to the variable `result` but displaying something else entirely. `int(x)` doesn't change `x`, it returns the converted `x`.

Comment: The last line should be `print(result)`, not `print(weight)`

Comment: @spagh-eddie Thank you for your help. I apologise.

I solved it the way you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the result instead of the weight

```
#float to int

result = int(weight)
print(result)
```